# Blocking IP is not working

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-ec2, iptables

This question has been asked several times but none of the answers works for me. This is very simple, I want to block some IP access to a server

I tried this:

.htaccess

```
Order Deny,Allow 
Deny from 151.101.52.84
```

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  151.101.52.0/24      anywhere
REJECT     tcp  --  151.101.52.84        anywhere             tcp reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
DROP       all  --  151.101.52.84        anywhere
DROP       all  --  151.101.52.84        anywhere
DROP       tcp  --  151.101.52.84        anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http limit: avg 100/min burst 200
```

/etc/hosts.deny

```
ALL : 151.101.52.84
```

netstat -te | grep 151.101

```
tcp        0      1 ip-*-*-*-*.us-we:51181 151.101.52.84:http          SYN_SENT    apache     800352623
```

Already restarted httpd

Even I blocked the IP via Amazon EC2 VPC

Need to restart entire server? Need something else with iptables?

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: Apache is 2.4.23

Comment: This netstat output looks like you connected from EC2 to 151.101.52.84

Comment: A2.4 does not support `allow`/`deny` any more. Use something like `<RequireAll>` / `Require all granted` / `Require not ip 1.2.3.4 ` / `</RequireAll>` instead. See also https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Comment: @Dusan you are in fact very correct.. already blocked a curl code that connects with Pinterest Api

Comment: To be clear: the connection in netstat is a connection that **you** initiated -- an outbound connection from you, @SuNcO, not an incoming connection.  Why do you think the iptables rules are not working?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Fail2Ban](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=what%20is%20fail2ban&oq=what%20is%20fa&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l4.5610j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

```
sudo apt-get install fail2ban
```